# How to remove SVG background when the background colour is a mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, background, background-removal

This is hard to explain, but I'll do it as best as I can. I have a graphic. It has a white background that I am seeking to remove. However, it seems there is actually no white background. The background is black with a white mask over it, producing the shape below. How can I invert the mask so that it is a shape instead of a mask, and that I can have a transparent background with a black shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no actual mask in the SVG. The entire design is made of white filled objects, which are grouped, and placed over a black filled rectangle. Shortcuts below are for PC, for Mac use Command instead of Ctrl.

1. Using the Selection Tool (V) select the graphic by clicking on a white area
2. Ungroup (Shift+Ctrl+G)
3. Do *Object > Compound Path > Make* (Ctrl+8)
4. Select all (Ctrl+A)
5. Open the Path Finder (Shift+Ctrl+F9) and hit the *Minus Front* button.

Enable the Transparency grid (Shift+Ctrl+D) to see it

[image]